# I don't see an option to upgrade from the Update Manager

Tags: 11.04, update-manager

Why is the Update manager of my Ubuntu 11.04 say "There are no updates to install"?

And no message "New Ubuntu release '11.10' is available" is displayed?

In software sources it is set to "Normal Releases".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that Update Manager is checking for LTS releases only or no releases. In software properties (`sudo software-properties-gtk`), on tab Updates, check the last option - Release upgrade. It should be set to Normal releases.

Also try running `sudo update-manager --check-dist-upgrades` and make sure you have all packages up-to-date (especially for Update Manager).

There are more upgrade strategies at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OneiricUpgrades

If nothing of this helps, try updating package information from console - what's the output of `sudo apt-get update` command?

Edit: The Maurizio's problem was caused by outdated mirrors. The mirror can be changed in Software Properties on the first tab, in *Download from* select Main server.

Comment: sudo software-properties-gtk --> Normal releases

Comment: sudo update-manager --check-dist-upgrades --> Your system is up-to-date; sudo apt-get update --> list of Http:// .. ; is the alternate CD the only way out ?

Comment: Regular install CD/flash disk should offer an option to upgrade the installed system - just boot from it, run installation and the option to upgrade should be offered to you. There're some more options mentioned at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades
I guess there's something fishy with your Update Manager or maybe you're using a stale mirror (this can be changed in Software Properties).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your suggestion about "using a stale mirror" did ring me a bell. It was enough to change the mirror in the settings(now Main server). Now 11.10 is available. Thank again.

Comment: Glad to see it worked out well. I've added the solution to my answer so if it worked for you, please mark the correct answer as accepted.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but 11.10 is not any more available. As soon as I upgraded 3 gnome packages, 11.10 disappeared again.

Comment: Looks like Update Manager wants to play peek-a-boo. Retry the `sudo update-manager --check-dist-upgrades` or try `sudo do-release-upgrade`. Also, rerun apt-get update.

Comment: I retried each command but no success

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Given that all your packages are up-to-date (especially update-manager ones) I think your best choice will be to upgrade using Oneiric installation CD/flash disk - either the standard install (installer should detect an existing installation and offer an upgrade) or the alternate install as described on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OneiricUpgrades#Upgrading_Using_the_Alternate_CD.2BAC8-DVD

Comment: You are right ! I think eventually I'll install/upgrade from the CD or format and install.

Answer (score 0):

First go in your file `/etc/apt/sources.list` logged as root and check of all main ubuntu packages didn't have # at the beginning of line. If yes, remove the #'s.

Then do `sudo apt-get update`

And finally `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

If it finds new packages, mainly the kernel modules, and you install them, you will get the new ubuntu.

Comment: The only packages with # are the software from the 'backports' repository and deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner. Do you think those packages are relevant ?

Comment: Strange...can you post your /etc/apt/sources.list in pastebin and give the link here? Backports isn't needed packages, but, maybe it's necessary. Did you tried dist-upgrade command? What you got?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/u/maurizioc/source.list

Comment: It's very strange. But, for my experience, it's better you don't upgrade to the newer version using dist-upgrade. Several applications starts crashing and dpkg-reconfigure didn't fix. If you would like use the new Ubuntu I recommend format and put a new one. Other thing, by your pastebin code, looks like you have already updated to the newer version of ubuntu. For you comprove that type `cat /etc/issue` and post what you got.

Comment: maurizio@mogs-W510:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 11.04 \n \l

Answer (score 0):

There is a choice in software sources if you want to be notified of normal releases or just LTS releases. Perhaps you've opted to only be notified of LTS releases?

Comment: Unluckily no : Normal releases is the choice

Comment: What mirror do you use? Is it possible that it hasn't synced, for some reason?

Comment: I have changed the mirror more than once. Nopw it is Main server